# A question about the formula for winding numbers in SMT 2021 Power Round

Tags: contest-math, winding-number

I was looking at the Power Round of Stanford Math Tournament and I came across this formula for a winding number of a curve:
$$w(\gamma)=\frac{1}{2πi}\int_0^{2π}\frac{\gamma’(s)}{\gamma(s)} \mathrm {ds}$$
Where $w(\gamma)$ is the winding number of the curve $\gamma(s)$, which is defined to be $\gamma : [0,2π] \to \mathbb C -\{0\}$, and $\gamma(0)=\gamma(2π)$

I evaluated the integral and found out that the winding number is always 0:
By letting $\gamma(s)=u$,

$$\int\frac{\gamma’(s)}{\gamma(s)} \mathrm {ds} =\int\frac1u \mathrm{du}=\ln(u)+C$$

So in this case, $$\int_0^{2π}\frac{\gamma’(s)}{\gamma(s)}=\ln(\gamma(2π))-\ln(\gamma(0))=0$$
Because $\gamma(2π)=\gamma(0)$

I know that this is clearly wrong by trying examples like $\gamma(s)=e^{is}$, because the integral would simply evaluate to 2πi, but where did my calculation go wrong?

Link to the problems pdf: https://sumo.stanford.edu/pdfs/smt2021/power-problems.pdf. (Pages 5-6)

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [contour integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration)? The expression $\int_a^b f(x)=F(b)-F(a)$ no longer necessarily holds in complex integration; instead it's dependent on the contour used to get there. You can no longer say that just because $\gamma(2\pi)=\gamma(0)$ that they're on the same branch of the logarithm and therefore that $\ln(\gamma(2\pi))=\ln(\gamma(0))$.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question! I’m not familiar with contour integrals but I’ll go check it out.